# Como executar um require_once dentro de um método de uma função que está sendo passada como parâmetro de outra função?

Tags: php, php-7

Estou tentando entender e fazer um router PHP.

index.php

```
<?php

    require_once 'config.php';
    require_once 'router.php';
    
?>
```

config.php

```
<?php   

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', true);
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

?
```

router.php

```
<?php   
    
    require_once 'Rotas.php';
    
    $rota = new Rotas;
    
    $rota->get("/", function() {
        require_once 'home.php';
    });
    
    $rota->get("/contato", "ConTato@form");

?>
```

Rotas.php  (a Classe)

```
<?php
        
    class Rotas {
        
        public function __construct() {}
        
        public function get (String $rota, $require = null){
            
            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === $rota) {
            
                if ( is_string($require) and $require !== "" ){
                    
                    $require = strtolower($require);
                    $require = explode('@', $require);
                    $class = ucfirst($require[0]);
                    $metodo = $require[1];
                    require_once $class .'.php';
                    $classe = new $class;
                    return $classe->$metodo();
                    
                }
                    
                if ( is_callable ($require) )                   
                    $require;
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
        
?>
```

home.php

```
<?php

 echo 'HOME';

?>
```

A) Todos os arquivos estão no mesmo diretório

B) O nome do **Virtual Host** que criei no **Apache 2.4** é **rotas.com**

Agora o problema:

Quando chamo no navegador **https://rotas.com/** o código entra normalmente na classe em

```
if ( is_callable ($require) )                   
    $require;
```

Mas não exibe o conteúdo do arquivo **home.php** e nem exibe erro algum.

No entanto, se eu fizer:

```
if ( is_callable ($require) )                   
    echo 123456;
```

Sai na tela corretamente o **123456**

Mas o require não funciona de jeito nenhum.

**Detalhe:** Quando faço: https://rotas.com/contato, tudo funciona corretamente.

O que estará errado para que o **require_once** não funcione?

Comment: Você não está invocando o callback. Neste trecho `if ( is_callable ($require) )                   
    $require;`, substitia `$require` por `$require()`.

Comment: Se quiser postar como resposta eu dou o aceite nela. Faz todo sentido, é uma chamada a um método,logo precisa dos (). Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não está invocando o callback.

No seguinte trecho:

```php
if ( is_callable ($require) ) 
    $require;
```

Substitua `$require` por `$require()`.